# Forms: transform multiple uploaded files (multiple => true) to multiple entities

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have an entity called `Image`. It contains a `file` attribute. I have also a form to create new `Image` entities with a `FileType` field which admits multiple uploads (`multiple => true`).

In case the user uploads multiple files, I would like to create the corresponding `Image` entities. What/where is the smartest way/place to do that?

Answer (score 0):

We can do this inside controller,

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();


if($request->isMethod('POST')){
    foreach($request->files as $uploadedFile) {            
        $name = 'yourname.jpg';
        $file = $uploadedFile->move($directory, $name);
        $image->setFile('yourname.jpg');

        $image = new Image();
        $em->persist($image);
        $em->flush();
    }
}

* Remember images will be saved in the table according to the order you put them in view :)
```

Comment: thanks, buth this code is not persisting entities, it is just saving the uploaded files.

Comment: I added the entity persist part. And we can use this code for multiple uploads because it's 'foreach' loop gets full php $_FILES array.